# malloc: *** error for object 0x10020a2c0: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Tags: c++, xcode

My rest of the program is working fine except when I try to use the += operator in the main, it throws an error.Assignment 4(1643,0x10013c3c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x10020a2c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug.
 Any help of how to fix it will be appreciated. 
This is the definition of my += function:

```
Student Student::operator+=(string item){
CheckOut(item);  //checkout is a member function of the class Student
return *this;
```

}

This is where the xcode compiler points the error at saying thread1: signal SIGABRT. I dont know what this error means.

```
Student::~Student(){
delete [] pointer; //it points error right here
pointer = NULL;
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure what you're intending to do here, but SIGABRT is commonly used by some C++ libraries to abort the program in case of critical errors. For example, glibc sends an SIGABRT in case of a detected double-delete or other heap(heap is a memory used when you use new operator) corruptions. So in short, I think you are trying to free a memory which has already been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your operator  function should return a reference  to Student:

Student& Student::operator+=(string item){ 
CheckOut(item); //checkout is a member function of the class Student return *this;
}

Comment: Thanks that worked! but now its giving me an error for the + operator too. The decleration:                                                                                                      
friend Student operator+(Student lhs, const string item); The definition:                                
Student operator+(Student& lhs, const string item){
    
    lhs+= item;
    return lhs;

}

Comment: You are hitting the same problem. You need to add a copy constructor because the default one copies the pointer so the copy shares the array which gets deleted when one gets destroyed and invalidating the pointer in the other.

Comment: Okay I am new to overloading, could you help me in how to make a copy constructor as its a friend function?

Comment: A quick Google gave this article https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-constructor-in-cpp/&ved=0ahUKEwiimYOI-_LZAhVkLsAKHZ1nBjoQFggwMAE&usg=AOvVaw2ucDMq7nq69MG1S4UPgRj8